# Cannot install Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-10, build-tools

During the setup of Visual Studio Community 2015 error popups saying that "A setup package is either missing or damaged". The package that missing is `BuildTools_MSBuild.msi`

[image: Screenshot of the error]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I assume that you've tried allowing it to connect to the Internet and clicking Retry?

Comment: Could you post the logs?

Comment: Where can i find the logs? @CodyGray It is connected to the internet.

Comment: collect the logs via this tool: aka.ms/vscollect

Comment: @Aslam, after you used the above tool, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to refer [Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=48159), try to install them. This should solve your issue.

If the error is unexpectedly still present, try the offline installer: On the [Download Page here](https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=48146) you can choose between the online installer called    **vs_community.exe,** which should be the one you're currently using. Below there is also **vs2015.com_deu.iso** avaliable. This should include all dependencies, I used it multiple times successfully at work, where the online installer is not working cause of a comany proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Lion I have i now installed with ISO

Answer (score 0):

If you already downloaded the ISO file of VS community 2015 with update 3, you need to verify the integrity of the ISO file, since the error message indicates a setup package is missing or damaged.

To check it, you can use the FCIV.exe tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/03/25/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing.aspx  to check the SHA1 value of the ISO, the expected value comes from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-iso-sha1-vs.aspx, any discrepancy means the ISO is corrupted.

Before the next installation, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any anti-virus software, clean up the %temp% folder, then re-run the installer as **administrator**.